# Container view controller app crash NSInternalInconsistencyException in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, exception, storyboard, childviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewcontroller` with a container view inside. In the `storyboard`, the container view is connected with the `UIViewcontroller` through an Embed Segue. I do not need to pass data from the `ParentView Controller` to the Child View Controller. The `ChildViewController` has a `CustomViewController` class, but since I don't need to pass any data between the 2 view controllers, the only reference between them is the embed segue in the `Storyboard`.

Every time I open the parent view controller, the app crashes, with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalIncosistencyException',
>       reason: 'NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings failed bacause either one of the values 
>       is nil, or there's something wrong with the way the macro is being invoked.
>       Cannot assign value nil for key "childView". Keys:(
>           childView
>       )'

Any idea what is causing this error and how to fix this? I'm working with Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3

Comment: `ChildViewController.view` is `nil`

Comment: can post your example code with question ?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when I tried to embed a sub-classed UITableViewController in a container view from Interface Builder. The problem was that layout was trying to find the view associated with the controller, but it had not been initialized.

**The fix for me was this:**

```
- (void)loadView {
   [super loadView];//<-- don't forget to call this!!!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the childView Instance is nil.